# Users who are only interested in final answers

Tags: discussion

I feel annoyed when someone doesn't reply to comments asking some illustrations about the question, the context of the problem or improving the quality of the question. They seem they don't have the time/ignore to reply to people who are interested in offering some *free* help. This might lead to understanding the question wrongly or even close it at the end. This category might include users who refuse to put some time learning LaTeX to improve the quality of the question. While some of them improve by time others get away with it because of some generous free editing.

**My question**

Is this behavior caused by the action of some helpers who *always* answer low-quality questions or edit them?

Is there a record of such users? such that we vote to close some repetitive low-quality questions by the same user?

Comment: If a user repeatedly posts low-quality questions and they are downvoted and closed, then the system can [ban them from asking more questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info). So there is some automated process which should (at least in theory) help to prevent from such behavior.

Comment: The complaint about LaTex is a very poor example to use to make your point. You might want to reflect on the point that your critique may in fact apply to this meta question.

Comment: @BillDubuque, a poor point in your opinion might not be for others. This is purely subjective.

Comment: @Zaid But almost everything on meta is subjective.

Comment: @BillDubuque, indeed. But I dont understand why you say it is a poor point ?

Comment: @Zaid Because of the the low-quality aspects of questions, this is perhaps the least important (and the easiest to remedy).

Comment: @Bill: Is it your subjective opinion that everything on meta is subjective? :-)

Answer (score 11):

The best way to respond to low quality content is to downvote and leave a comment explaining why. You can't do anything to make someone who fundamentally doesn't care, and trying to seems like an exercise in futility.